# Tricky distance matrix calculation and how to cleverly avoid out of bounds

Tags: python, numpy

I have the layout of a warehouse with racks and aisles where items are picked from locations on the racks while traversing the aisles:

[image]

I want to compute a distance matrix between each pair of nodes/locations in the following way. Let `x` be the across aisle coordinate and `z` be the coordinate along the aisle as shown in the figure above. If `x_1 = x_2` the two nodes are located on the same aisle and the distance is easily computed as `t_12 = z_2-z_1` where `t_12` is the distance between node 1 and 2. Otherwise, the distance between the two nodes can be calculated as follows:

```
t_12 = min( |z_1 - B| + |x_2 - x_1| + |z_2 - B|, |z_1 - M| + |x_2 - x_1| + |z_2 - M|, |z_1 - T| + |x_2 - x_1| + |z_2 - T|)
```

since there are 3 ways to go from node 1 to node 2 and the shortest is chosen. `T`, `M` and `B` are the z-coordinate of top cross aisle, middle cross aisle and the bottom cross aisle.

This is what I've done so far:

```
import numpy as np

x_coordinates = np.linspace(0, 320, 33).astype(int)

z_coordinates = np.linspace(0, 30, 31).astype(int)

print("x coordinates = ")
print(x_coordinates)
print("z coordinates = ")
print(z_coordinates)

B = 0
M = 15
T = 31

def dist_calc(x, z):
    mat = np.zeros((len(x), len(z)))
    for i in range(len(x_coordinates)):
        for j in range(len(z_coordinates)):
            mat[i][j] = min(np.abs(z[i] - B) + np.abs(x[j] - x[j + 1]) + np.abs(z[i + 1] - B),
                            np.abs(z[i] - M) + np.abs(x[j] - x[j + 1]) + np.abs(z[i + 1] - M),
                            np.abs(z[i] - T) + np.abs(x[j] - x[j + 1]) + np.abs(z[i + 1] - T))
    return mat


Distances = dist_calc(x_coordinates, z_coordinates)
```

I have two questions:

1. I don't see how I should incorporate the case when `x_1 = x_2`. I think that the way I've defined the coordinates makes it impossible to specify the condition that two nodes are on the same aisle, i.e have the same `x`-coordinate.
2. Of course I understand that I will get an index out of bounds error since I'm trying to access element `i+1` and `j+1` in arrays of length `i` and `j` respectively. Is there a way to circumvent this problem? Do I need to append an extra zero to the `x` and `z` coordinate arrays in the beginning?

Comment: This is an interesting problem! Before I attempt: you are unable to pass through racks, and given your x and z coords, you have 2 by 32 racks? Or are nodes allowed to exist "next to" racks? I am a bit unsure where the nodes exist on the x-z plane.

Comment: Correct, no passing! However, each rack has multiple z-coordinates because each rack is also split into several bins and each of these bins correspond to one z-coordinate. To be precise, there are 31 z-coordinates. The nodes only exist on the middle of the aisles. So the x-coordinate of the nodes are [0, 10, ..., 330] while their z-coordinates are [0, 1, ..., 31]. These form a grid (0,0), (0,1), ... , (330, 31). I hope my explanation is clear, don't hesitate to ask if not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your comment, you stated that the last point is (330,31), which is inconsistent with your linspace. The biggest mistake is that you are iterating over the individual axes, whilst you should iterate over all combinations of the coordinates. I separated out the distance calculation and the matrix generation, because generating a 1088x1088 matrix is a bit expensive.

```
import numpy as np

x_c = np.linspace(0, 330, 34).astype(int)
z_c = np.linspace(0, 31, 32).astype(int)

print("x coordinates = ")
print(x_c,len(x_c))
print("z coordinates = ")
print(z_c,len(z_c))
print()

B = 0
M = 15
T = 31


def dist_calc(p1,p2,B,M,T):
    return min( abs(p1[1] - B) + abs(p2[0] - p1[0]) + abs(p2[1] - B) ,
                abs(p1[1] - M) + abs(p2[0] - p1[0]) + abs(p2[1] - M) ,
                abs(p1[1] - T) + abs(p2[0] - p1[0]) + abs(p2[1] - T) ) * (p1 != p2)


def gen_mat(x,z,B,M,T):
    c = [(i,j) for i in x for j in z]
    mat = np.zeros((len(c), len(c)))
    for i,p1 in enumerate(c):
        for j,p2 in enumerate(c):
                mat[i,j] = dist_calc(p1,p2,B,M,T)                   
    return mat

print('Distance between (200,31) and (150,2) should be 200-150=50;31-2=29;50+29=79')
print()

D = gen_mat(x_c,z_c,B,M,T)
c = [(i,j) for i in x_c for j in z_c]
print('By using a distance matrix:')
print(D[c.index((200,31)),c.index((150,2))])
print()

print('By using the raw distance function:')
print(dist_calc((200,31),(150,2),B,M,T))
```

Output:

```
x coordinates = 
[  0  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90 100 110 120 130 140 150 160 170
 180 190 200 210 220 230 240 250 260 270 280 290 300 310 320 330] 34
z coordinates = 
[ 0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23
 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31] 32

Distance between (200,31) and (150,2) should be 200-150=50;31-2=29;50+29=79

By using a distance matrix:
79.0

By using the raw distance function:
79
```

Comment: I now see my error and what you have done, I drew an plt.imshow(D) and the structure of the matrix seems correct. You're absolutely correct in that looping through all combinations of pairs of points, and not coordinates, is the way to go. However, the matrix that is generated when I run gen_mat is 1088x1088 and not 1023x1023 as you seem to suggest.  Nontheless, thanks a lot and I learned a lot from this answer. That enumerate() function was particularly new for me!

Comment: You're welcome; my solution is not optimized by any means. The scipy library has the cityblock functions, which looks like this function but I could not get it to work. I don't know how you got 1088x1088, because if I understand correctly, you have 32 by 31 trays, and the robot can move around all of them. Anyways, good luck.

Comment: That's no problem since this computation is only required to be done once for a certain warehouse layout thus there are no requirements on run-time. The 1088x1088 is what I see when I run your code. The variable explorer tells me D is an {ndarray: (1088, 1088)}.

Comment: Whoops, you're right. I think I erroneously remembered the values from the incorrect linspace. Corrected.

Comment: I think there is something I'm not getting in the matrix D. If I calculate the distance from (0,1) to (0,1) I get 2 using the dist_calc function. I just ran `print(dist_calc((0,1),(0,1),B,M,T))`.

Comment: Yes it seems as if the condition that if x1 = x2, i.e if the points are on the same aisle, then mat[i,j] = abs(y_1 - y_2), have been forgotten.

Comment: Fixed it with just 9 chars!